# Using AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading in Swift

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm curious if there is a Swifty, safe way to use `AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading` without having to hard code the keys I'm using. Specifically, I'd like to call `loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys:completionHandler:)` with the key `"availableMdiaCharacteristicsWithMediaSelectionOptions"`, but it currently isn't possible to get a `String` from any kind of `KeyPath`-based solution. I would love it if there was some kind of way to retrieve the name of a property in such a way that it would be checked at compile time whether the property exists. Is there such an API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was `#keyPath`. I for some reason thought that `KeyPath` had replaced `#keyPath` in Swift, but `#keyPath(AVAsset. availableMediaCharacteristicsWithMediaSelectionOptions)` gives the string `"availableMediaCharacteristicsWithMediaSelectionOptions"` which is exactly what I want.